# putting spike timings to time bins in an array, in python

Tags: python

I have spike times from an electrode as follows:

```
array([ 11.     ,   0.22825,   0.29775,       nan,       nan,       nan,
             nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,
             nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,
             nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,
             nan])
```

11 is the electrode number, I choose a time bin of 2ms and I want to put spikes that occurs between 200ms to 300 ms to these time bins, "nan" means there is no spike.So I want to put spikes that occur between 200ms-202ms to one time bin and if there is no spike  between 202ms-204ms then put 0 there and so on.

It is necessary that I find a way that can be scaled, for example if I want to change the time bin to 4ms and with one parameter this should be done. It might seem complicated but I thought maybe Python experts have very quick solution. I will appreciate any help, suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output you want here?

Answer (score 0):

[`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) seems to do what you want:

```
>>> arr = numpy.array([11., 0.22825, 0.29775])
>>> bins, _ = numpy.histogram(arr[1:], bins=numpy.linspace(0.2, 0.3, 101))
>>> bins
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```